# Why \hskip and \hspace* Produce Shifts of Different Measures

Tags: horizontal, unit-of-measure, measure

I have noticed, for example, that `\hskip 20pt` and `hspace*{20pt}` produce horizontal shifts not of the same length.

Consider, for instance,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\drop % To drop the start of the paragraph below the top of the picture.
\setlength\drop{10pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,},fill=green!30, inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont
    \vspace{\drop}%
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-4
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \drop+0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hspace{\columnsep}}% 
      \hskip 20pt \textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE}}  \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      \hspace*{20pt} \textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE}}  \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      %\hspace{20pt} \textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE}}  \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      \textbf{\textit{\lipsum[4]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip 20pt
\LARGE

************************* \vskip 0pt
\noindent A sentence. \hskip 20pt (hskip 20pt) \\
A sentence. \hspace*{20pt} (hspace*{20pt}) \\
A sentence. \hspace{20pt} (hspace{20pt}) 
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

As you can see in both the tikzpicture and in the sentences, there is a slight difference in the horizontal shift depending upon whether `hskip` or `hspace*` is used. (Incidentally, it appears that `hspace*` and `hspace` produce the same measured shift.)

QUESTION: Can anyone account for this difference? I would think that since 20pt=20pt, `\hskip 20pt` and `\hspace*{20pt}` would both produce the same shift. But clearly, they don't.

Thank you.

Comment: this is no different to `\LaTeX xxx` and `\LaTeX{} xxx` producing different space.

Comment: with the text as you have it now with just a title to the right of the image and no cut-in to the main paragraph at all you could vastly simplyfy this coding and remove all the code relating to `\hangindent` and `\raisebox` (the markup `\\[-5pt]~\smallskip` is just weird and isn't needed at all)

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comment, but to ask the question I posed---I basically used  an example of a box I had close at hand. The question did not pertain to the box per se, but as to why there exists a perceived difference in  measure of the two shift  commands. Then, I added the part involving the sentences to illustrate what I was asking did not pertain to the tikzpicture solely. I hope to apply later, when I get a little time, what you say about the spacing command to see if I can improve the coding efficiency of the tikzpicture. Thanks again.

Comment: sure I realise it's unrelated to this question but I just thought as I'd comment as originally in earlier questions you had the image set in like a drop-cap initial, but now it's simply an image above the paragraph and needs no special coding at all.

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes; I appreciate the advice---for as you know, this picture has given me some considerable trouble  in the past and actually, still does in regards to the ease of placing a centered title without going through a series of manual adjustments potentially for each picture. Your comment is indeed appreciated and I hope to study it later this evening. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space after `pt` in `\hskip` is dropped, but not the one after the brace of `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
X\hskip 20pt X

X\hspace{20pt}X

X\hspace{20pt} X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This you for your informative  answer.

Answer (score 2):

The space after `{20pt}`  counts as a space.  The space after `20pt`  does not.

As to why, the right brace in `{20pt}`  terminates the reading of the argument, and so the following space is seen as a typographic space.  On the other hand, when `20pt`  is being digested, the space is digested while reading the length argument, and thus no longer acts as a typographic space (a space is an allowable terminator on a length specification).  If you wrote it as `\hskip 20pt{}` , the trailing space would then be digested as a typographic space again.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\drop % To drop the start of the paragraph below the top of the picture.
\setlength\drop{10pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,},fill=green!30, inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont
    \vspace{\drop}%
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-4
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \drop+0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\hspace{\columnsep}}% 
      \hskip 20pt \textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE}}  \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      \hspace*{20pt}\textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE}}  \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      %\hspace{20pt} \textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE}}  \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      \textbf{\textit{\lipsum[4]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip 20pt
\LARGE

************************* \vskip 0pt
\noindent A sentence. \hskip 20pt (hskip 20pt) \\
A sentence. \hspace*{20pt}(hspace*{20pt}) \\
A sentence. \hspace{20pt}(hspace{20pt}) 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two very good answers presented themselves at the same time, and sorry I could not accept both (sounds almost like a Robert Frost poem). I did not know which one to choose and a flipped a coin. I would like to thank you for you excellent answer and for your kind help once again.